# Host .net6 app under .net framework app in Azure

Tags: .net, azure, .net-6.0

I have an AppService hosted in Azure under site\wwwroot, built on .net framework 4.7. I also have a new web app, built on .net6, which I deployed as a Virtual Application under the site\wwwroot\scheduler.

Now I need both of them to work altogether, so if I would go to mywebsite.azure.. URL, I would be able to see the old AppService, and mywebsite.azure.../scheduler - to see the new .net 6 app.

At the moment when I run the second URL, I get a generic 500 err and cannot identify, where is the issue.

Is it overall possible to host .net 6 app under .net framework app in Azure?

Comment: .NET 6 is .NET *Core* 6. It's a completely different runtime

Comment: I understand, but maybe in Azure there are some tricks to make them working altogether?

Answer (score 0):

The Azure App service host has both the frameworks installed in which you can be verified by running the cmdlets from the console `dotnet-info` and `reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP"`.

> Is it overall possible to host .net 6 app under .net framework app in Azure?

Theoretically, as a virtual application you should be able to run the .NET core app, make sure you do not have any conflicting `web.config` files.

[image: AzureAppServiceConsole]